Why is my proxy not working? (React & Node.js)
I am working with a React app (create using create-react-app) and using Node.js v.20.11.1 and when I try to send a POST request from my React app to my Node.js backend, the URL isn't proxied properly. I have tried using packages such as CORS to see if it would fix it but I am just completely lost on how to fix this. I am new to React and Javascript altogether so some help would be greatly appreciated.
index.js (Node.js backend)
// Imports
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

// Creating server instance
const app = express();

// CORS Integration
app.use(cors({
  origin:"localhost:8080",
}));

//URLS
const dbURL = "mongodb+srv://lovdaniel11:BgZ5A7LQdZoW75SG@cluster0.n61xkiw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";

// Serve static files from the React build directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.json());  

// All other routes should redirect to the React app (for client-side routing)
app.post('/api/submitted', (req, res) => {
  // Log the submitted data
  console.log(req.body);
  // Send a response back to the client
  res.json({ message: 'Received POST request at /api/submitted' });
});
// Mongo DB Integration
mongoose.connect(dbURL)
.then(() => {
  console.info("connected to db");
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.log(`error: ${e}`);
});

// Starts server instance
const port = 8080; // Use environment variable for port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server list`ening on port ${port}));

Fetch Request (React)
        let questionData = {
            question:questionVal,
            author:authorVal
        }

        fetch("/api/submitted", {
            method:'post',
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(questionData)
        })
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{console.log(data);});  

package.json (React)

{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "options": {
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
    "allowedHosts": [
      "localhost",
      ".localhost"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"
  }
}

package.json (Node.js)

{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "options": {
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
    "allowedHosts": [
      "localhost",
      ".localhost"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"
  }
}

Browser Error

Ideally the contents of Question and Author would be printed in my Node.js console.

Please [edit] your question title to describe the actual problem you're having or question you're asking. The tag information should not be in the title at all, and *Why isn't my proxy working?" says nothing about the actual issue. If it was working, you wouldn't need to post here. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

The error code 404 means the URI doesn't exist where you're trying to make the POST API call.
In your screenshot, it says http://localhost:3000/api/submitted.

That means your Node.js application should be running on http://localhost:3000.  Check if your you Node.js app running on this address/port or not?
If not then use the same port as nodejs in the react API call.

Check your React app address/port. You should be using your react app port in CORS config. If your React app is running on port 5555. The config should look like this:
app.use( cors ({ origin:"localhost:5555" }));



app.use(cors({
origin: "localhost:8080",
}));
In this code add frontend localhost and port on which it is running. You are using port 8080 to run the backend server, and applying cors to the same port 8080 (must be different for frontend).
Check this out:  https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Please all the bellow code. It will solve your issue.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:8000'];
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    return next();
});

